# How to automate desktop application developed using electron framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ui-automation, spectron

Our application is developed using electron framework. it is a standalone application. I have seen that spectron is the framework which is used to automate electron application. but i am not sure whether it is applicable for desktop application. Please confirm the same.

I have installed nodejs and spectron. 
I have written a code launch application as mention in the following site
https://electron.atom.io/spectron/

File Name : First.js

```
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')

var app = new Application({
  path: 'C:\Users\ramass\AppData\Local\Programs\ngsolutions\ngsolutions.exe'
})

app.start().then(function () {
  // Check if the window is visible
  return app.browserWindow.isVisible()
}).then(function (isVisible) {
  // Verify the window is visible
  assert.equal(isVisible, true)
}).then(function () {
  // Get the window's title
  return app.client.getTitle()
}).then(function (title) {
  // Verify the window's title
  assert.equal(title, 'My App')
}).then(function () {
  // Stop the application
  return app.stop()
}).catch(function (error) {
  // Log any failures
  console.error('Test failed', error.message)
})
```

i have tried to run the script using command

> node First.js

But i am getting error saying that

```
C:\spectronprgs>node First.js

Error: Cannot find module 'spectron'
```

Please let me know whether I am going towards right path 
how to launch .exe file using spectron framework
how to run the script

Answer (score 2):

run the following from the command line.

```
npm install --save-dev spectron
```

Then see if you can find the module. You never mentioned in your post how you installed spectron.

Comment: I have downloaded all the dependencies specified in the github documentation. Now I am able to launch the application.But I am not able to  find the methods specified there.
For Example Please find the below link
https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/143
elementIdText is a method of client object.

But this method is not available when download all the dependencies and try to code.

Comment: I have downloaded all the dependencies specified in the github documentation. Now I am able to launch the application.But I am not able to  find the methods specified there.
For Example Please find the below link
https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/143
elementIdText is a method of client object.

But this method is not available when download all the dependencies and try to code.
can any one help me